# How to use applicationDbContext with n tier MVC architecture

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-core

I am trying to implement N tier in MVC. I had a question on how would I use dependency injection to inject applicationDbContext in Data layer, because when I call DAL from Business Layer(BLL) then it expects parameter of applicationDbContext in constructor.

```
public class ProductTypesDAL
{
    private readonly ApplicationDbContext _db;

    protected ProductTypesDAL(ApplicationDbContext db)
    {
        _db = db;
    }

    public List<ProductType> GetProductTypes()
    {
        return _db.ProductType.ToList();
    }
}
```

Business Layer:

```
public class ProductTypesBLL
{
    private ProductTypesDAL objProductTypeDAL = new ProductTypesDAL(); //Error when I initialize

    public List<ProductType> getProductTypes()
    {
        return objProductTypeDAL.GetProductTypes();
    }
}
```

I have applicationDBContext in DAL Layer. Is there something else that I am missing?

Thanks,
Ben

Comment: why are you creating these layers at all?  especially in the context of your example.  you'd be passing an dbcontext down the stack just to call a method on the the dbcontext.

Answer (score 0):

If you would to write all product type methods in your DAL, than make it static.

Try this:

```
public static class ProductTypesDAL
{   
    protected ProductTypesDAL() 
    {
    }

    public List<ProductType> GetProductTypes()
    {
        var _db = new ApplicationDbContext();

        return _db.ProductType.ToList();
    }
}

public class ProductTypesBLL
{    
    public List<ProductType> getProductTypes()
    {
        return ProductTypesDAL.GetProductTypes();
    }
}
```

One thing you need to make sure tho is that this class: ApplicationDbContext is the correct name of the class that derives from the DbContext and that it holds the DbSets.